# css rule not being applied in safari, but ok in firefox

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I'm trying to figure out why this rule is not being applied in Safari or IE

```
.navbar-inner {
    min-height: 40px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    background-color: #333333 !important;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgb(74, 74, 74), rgb(54, 54, 54)) !important;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    border: 1px solid rgb(212, 212, 212);
    border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.067);
}
```

Basically, I'm trying to overwrite the background color of the navbar in bootstrap.
as you can see, I've added the !important keyword, just to test for css specificity issues.  That still didn't resolve the issue.
Can you give me any suggestions for troubleshooting this?  It works fine in Firefox.... 
and I'm just testing in Chrome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Different browsers use different gradient properties. [This](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/) is a really good tool for generating them.

For this you can use:

```
.navbar-inner {
    background: rgb(74,74,74); /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgb(74,74,74) 1%, rgb(54,54,54) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(1%,rgb(74,74,74)), color-stop(100%,rgb(54,54,54))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgb(74,74,74) 1%,rgb(54,54,54) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgb(74,74,74) 1%,rgb(54,54,54) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgb(74,74,74) 1%,rgb(54,54,54) 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgb(74,74,74) 1%,rgb(54,54,54) 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#4a4a4a', endColorstr='#363636',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}
```

`!important` shouldn't be necessary when trying to override Bootstrap default styling. Just make sure your Bootstrap styling is added to the page *before* your custom styling.